# What is happening in the following code?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

This code is used in the accelerometer
method.

It uses a CGPoint variable called playerVelocity.

```
-(void)accelerometer:(UIAccelerometer *)accelerometer didAccelerate:(UIAcceleration *)acceleration  
{  
    //controls how quickly the velocity decelerates
    float deceleration = 0.4f;

    //determines how sensitive the accelerometer reacts
    float sensitivity = 6.0f;

    //how fast the velocity can be at most
    float maxVelocity = 100;

    playerVelocity.x = playerVelocity.x *deceleration + acceleration.x *sensitivity;


    if (playerVelocity.x < -maxVelocity) 
    {
        playerVelocity.x = -maxVelocity;
    }
    else if (playerVelocity.x > maxVelocity)
    {
        playerVelocity.x = maxVelocity;
    }
}
```

Now I know that the `playerVelocity` variable is a CGPoint so I imagine it as a X,Y Graph.
I'm assuming that wherever the `playerVelocity` variable is resting (let's say 150,0), it first multiplies whatever coordinates by 0.4 whenever the accelerometer input is received (which is by the iPhone being tilted)and it then add's the `accelerometer.x` multiplied by 6.0 to the `playerVelocity` variable. Is this correct?

Later on in another method, this is added to my other objects position via

```
CGPoint pos = playerObject.position;
pos.x+= playerVelocity.x;
playerObject.position = pos;
```

What I'm confused about is what exactly is happening behind the scenes here. Is my assumption above correct?

When the playerVelocity is at 150,0 and is multiplied by 0.4, does the X coordinate of the playerVelocity variable gradually reduce, i.e. 150,0  ,   145,0   , 130,0     etc.. ?

If I figure this out I'll then know how my `playerObject` is moving.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have a constant deceleration (.4) that is opposing motion in whatever direction you are currently traveling subtracted from the acceleration as received via the accelerometer, which is multiplied by a constant. This value is then added to your current velocity. So you are essentially adding the difference of (acceleration from accelerometer - constant deceleration) to your current velocity for each calculation.

Comment: I see. 
So the motion basically happens in my other method(which is an update method) that adds the velocity to the position.Ok, I understand, thank you.